# is it possible to detect zigbee traffice via wireshark? if yes , how?

Tags: wireless, wireshark

I have a zigbee access point. I am not able to detect its network. Also, unable to capture its traffic using wireshark like we capture wifi traffic. Can someone tell me what should be done to analyse the zigbee traffice

Answer (score 4):

Wireshark does have decoders for [IEEE 802.15.4](https://wiki.wireshark.org/IEEE_802.15.4), upon which, ZigBee is based. Before you can analyze the traffic, however, you do need a mechanism to capture the data.

You will need to acquire hardware that can capture the correct frequencies. 802.15.4 devices may use one of three possible frequency bands for operation (868/915/2450 MHz) and ZigBee operates in the 2.4 GHz, 784 MHz, 868 MHz, and 915 MHz ranges.

The are some dedicated hardware devices that can capture ZigBee traffic. [Wireshark describes](https://wiki.wireshark.org/IEEE_802.15.4) the following products:

- [IEEE 802.15.4 Wireshark USB Stick](http://www.ubisys.de/en/engineering/products-wireshark-802.15.4.html) at € 199.
- [Exegin Q51 IEEE/802.15.4 ZigBee Transceiver](http://www.exegin.com/hardware/q51app.php) at $500.

The are some other products not mentioned on the wireshark page:

- [Sewio UWB Sniffer](http://www.sewio.net/product/uwb-sniffer/) at $500.

You may also be able to use a Software Defined Radio (SDR) to capture and decode the traffic. The [HackRF](https://greatscottgadgets.com/hackrf/) device can cost around $330 but I couldn't find any documentation describe the decoding of 802.15.4.

A [Presentation](http://www.willhackforsushi.com/presentations/toorcon11-wright.pdf) from Joshua Wright describes a KillerBee, a ZigBee exploitation framework. The presentation recommends a [AVR RZ Raven USB Stick (RZUSB,
$40)](http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-67532/l/avr-rz-usb-stick-module) for sniffing 802.15.4.

The [KillerBee](https://github.com/riverloopsec/killerbee) Framework includes a program called `zbdump` which has the ability to output to libcap format files, so you can then use wireshark to analyze it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. So what you are trying to say is our normal NIC card in laptops cant capture zigbee traffic right? If so, we wont be able to detect the zigbee network under the list of network names listed by our laptop right?

Comment: @user3601346 That is my understanding. While the frequencies may be in the same spectrum, a typical WiFi card's hardware will limit the ability to read traffic other than WiFi.

Comment: Thanks again. So just like we add some bluetooth drivers to our system to detect bluetooth devices, do we have some zigbee drivers? Or, do we have to go for some hardware that supports zigbee as a typical NIC card wont read zigbee??

Comment: It depends on the hardware. The wireshark page mentions that the `Exegin ZigBee Transceiver` actually forwards the traffic it receives over TCP/IP, so I assume (though I can't say for sure), that it should operate independently. The Joshua Wright presentation mentions on slide 19 that the `AVR RZ Raven USB Stick`  "Default RZUSB firmware accommodates sniffing...", though that is talking about the firmware of the hardware, not drivers in your OS. You will probably need the [downloads](http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-67532/l/avr-rz-usb-stick-module#downloads) for the RZUSB installed.

Comment: But it says the exegin plugin has already been donated to wireshark and could be used with any capture device ??

Comment: My understanding is that Exegin donated the 802.15.4 decode to wireshark. Thus, it doesn't mater what hardware you use to capture the data, as long as it is saved in a libcap compatible format. Drivers control the hardware, but the decoder is independent of the hardware you use to capture the data. The wireshark page above has a sample `pcap` file with ZigBee traffic in it that you can download and analyze with wireshark right now, no drivers required (because the driver controls the hardware, hardware is used to produce the `pcap` file).

Comment: Check out the "Required Hardware" section of the [killer bee project on github](https://github.com/riverloopsec/killerbee)

Answer (score 0):

They (the [ZigBee microcontroller](http://www.atmel.com/products/wireless/zigbee/)) use [IEEE 802.15.4](https://standards.ieee.org/about/get/802/802.15.html) as their protocol across the 900MHZ  - 2.4GHZ spectrum. As long as the device running wireshark has access to that spectrum you shouldn't have a problem. See [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/IEEE_802.15.4).

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZigBee) mentions ZigBee using the 915 MHz and 2.4 GHz in the US.